# In Amazon lex im getting error as "Intent Readyforfullfilment" after selecting the Return Parameters to client option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I have created the an chatbot application in Amazon-lex console.
Then I have added the intents as per my requirement.
But if I have entered the some message as *"dsfdsf"* then it showing error as

> "Intent FILEDOC is ReadyForFulfillment: filedocOfAvasoft:dsfdsf"

[image: Please see this screenshot of chat application]

Answer (score 3):

I know its probably too late already, but I had a similar issue today. I thought posting here might help someone who might accidentally stumble on this thread. If your intent says "**ReadyForFulfillment**", then you have probably forgot to specify the business logic linking. This is done form the Lex intent declaration screen by selecting either "**AWS Lambda Function**" or "**Return parameters to client**" radio buttons under the "**Fulfillment**" section. That worked for me.

Comment: Thanks man! In my case was this, combined with the silly mistake of not having hit the "Save Intent" button.